# C++ QueryFullProcessImageNameA alternative for Windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows

I have found the following code in several places Google, so I have started testing. It works OK ( ish ) but the problem is "**QueryFullProcessImageNameA**" because according to Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx this function works on minimum Windows Vista.

**The code:**

```
int Is64(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PBOOL Is64)
    {
        int Status = 1;
        HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        LPVOID lpFile = 0;
        DWORD dwFileSize = 0, dwReaded = 0, dwSize = MAX_PATH;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders = 0;
        char Path[MAX_PATH];

        //Minimum supported client Windows Vista[desktop apps only]
        //TODO
        if (!QueryFullProcessImageNameA(ProcessHandle, 0, Path, &dwSize) || !Is64)
        {
            Status = 2;
            goto EXIT;
        }
        hFile = CreateFileA(Path, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
        if (!hFile || hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            Status = 3;
            goto EXIT;
        }
        dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, 0);
        lpFile = VirtualAlloc(0, dwFileSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        if (!lpFile)
        {
            Status = 4;
            goto EXIT;
        };
        if (!ReadFile(hFile, lpFile, dwFileSize, &dwReaded, 0))
        {
            Status = 5;
            goto EXIT;
        }
        NtHeaders = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS>((reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(lpFile) + PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(lpFile)->e_lfanew));
        if (!NtHeaders ||
            NtHeaders->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        {
            Status = 6;
            goto EXIT;
        }
        if (NtHeaders->FileHeader.Machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 || NtHeaders->FileHeader.Machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64)
        {
            *Is64 = true;
            Status = 7;
            goto EXIT;
        }
        if (NtHeaders->FileHeader.Machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386)
        {
            *Is64 = false;
            Status = 7;
            goto EXIT;
        }
    EXIT:
        if (hFile)
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        if (lpFile)
            VirtualFree(lpFile, dwFileSize, MEM_DECOMMIT);
        return true;
    }
```

So my question is, is there an "alternative" for "QueryFullProcessImageNameA" which would work on Windows XP as well, without changing this function much ?

Thank you

Comment: [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687420(v=vs.85).aspx) with *ProcessImageFileName* perfect worked on xp. the `QueryFullProcessImageName` with `PROCESS_NAME_NATIVE` exactly use this. for win32 path used *ProcessImageFileNameWin32* which available from vista

Comment: and if you need only some exe image information (guess based on your code snippet) you can simply query `ProcessImageInformation` which return to you `SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION`

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, I am only interested in a reliable way of determining if the process is x32 or x64 bit. I will have a try with your recommendation.

Comment: *in a reliable way of determining if the process is x32 or x64 bit* simply call `IsWow64Process` in this case. or direct *ProcessWow64Information* with the same 
 
`NtQueryInformationProcess `

Comment: In my tests, IsWow64Process does not work properly in some windows editions...

Comment: this only say that your test have mistake. `IsWow64Process` which simply call `NtQueryInformationProcess(  ProcessWow64Information)` - 100% correct show 32/64 bit. your test is wrong

Comment: I disagree, you should read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: and so what ? what concrete you mean ?

Comment: It will not work on Windows XP lower than SP2, and it is not reliable... if you read it. I need reliable way of checking on ANY Windows...

Comment: if you need lower than sp2 (which already think not exist in real word) - use `NtQueryInformationProcess( ProcessWow64Information)` - however xp not exist in 64 bit variant at all. so called xp x64- is really win2003 x64 (nt 5.2)  and about *it is not reliable* - form where you decide this ?? this is 100% **reliable**

Comment: I have virtual machines running all types of windows and tested... and I also have windows xp x64 edition "unofficial" ( which people use! ) ...

Comment: and so what ? are this fail ? for me simply very interesting, why you decide this **is not reliable** ? however if want use this even on win2000 or nt4 - call direct NtQueryInformationProcess( ProcessWow64Information)

Comment: *windows xp x64 edition* - this is only marketing name for users. if you check version - this is **5.2** - so this is windows 2003 x64. and `IsWow64Process` here exist of course. `NtQueryInformationProcess` exist from nt4. so you always can call it. and `ProcessWow64Information` give 100% reliable way detect are this 32/64 bit process. if it return - ivalid info class error - (win200,nt4) - this mean 32 bit

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, I shall test more...

Comment: yes, can test. but again `IsWow64Process` is **absolute reliable**. it can not exist (< xp sp2) but if exist of course give correct result, if you have correct process handle. internally it call `NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess,ProcessWow64Information,&wow, sizeof(wow),0)`. if you mean *technique is not a reliable way to detect whether the operating system is a 64-bit version of Windows* - so you confuse *Windows* and *process*. you of course can not determinate are *windows* is 64 or 32 bit system with this api. but you can determinate wow process.

Comment: @RbMm I understand, checkout my code: https://pastebin.com/xYKqrwT1 would it be "reliable" way to do it ?

Comment: 1 - you not need `PROCESS_VM_READ` - remove this. `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` you need only on xp/2003. if you detect vista+ (major version >= 6) better use `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`. you forget close process handle - what is serious error. you not check any errors. this code is very not ok.

Comment: if you want full support all versions (even very old without GepProcAddress) - direct call `void* wow; NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess,ProcessWow64Information,&‌​wow, sizeof(wow),0). `

Comment: @RbMm It's not the complete code, it's just the part I check if x64... But I will try your method too !

Comment: in any case at compile time if defined `_WIN64` - you run on 64-bit windows. if not - you can call `ProcessWow64Information` or `IsWow64Process` for **self** process - if you wow - windows 64 bit. if no (or error/IsWow64Process not exist) - windows 32 bit. for detect some *process* 32 or 64 bit - call  `ProcessWow64Information` or `IsWow64Process` for **this** process - and this is 100% reliable on all versions

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, will do.

Comment: @RbMm You information is correct, if you post an answer I will accept it :) BTW, could we get in touch somehow ? I see from your profile that you have a waste experience in WinAPI and that is what I do all day and I have some questions if possible.