# Files in directory with wildcard on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

how can I easy get all files paths from path containing a wildcards? For example: *C:/Data*Set/Files*/*.txt* and I wrote it on Linux using `glob` function but I can't do it on Windows :/

`FindFirstFile` unfortunately doesn't support wildcards in directory names.

I think there should be a Windows solution available but I can't find it.

Comment: _"`FindFirstFile` unfortunately doesn't support wildcards in directory names."_ __Yes__ it does.  I use this for a complete directory tree traversal program.  You can't have more than 1 `*` so you have to write the code yourself.

Comment: @RichardCritten: You are referring to the fact that both files and directories matching the last component are returned, and not claiming that wildcards are allowed anywhere except the last component, correct?  Also, you're claiming that `c:\path\file*.*` isn't allowed?  I find that very surprising.

Comment: @BenVoigt  - need understand how `FindFirstFile[Ex]` work. this is shell over [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile). `FindFirstFile` need divide input name to folder name (which will be opened in used as *FileHandle*) and search mask used as *FileName*. mask can be only in file name. folder must have exact name without wildcards to opened first. and `*.*` common mistake, converted to `*` by `FindFirstFile`.

Comment: so `c:\path\file*` - search `file*` in `c:\path` folder. when `c:\path\file\*` - search `*` (all files) in `c:\path\file` folder

Comment: for recursive directory search we anyway need recursive call `FindFirstFileEx`. all what wee need - use **different search masks** on different level. `Data*Set` on level 0, `Files*` on level 1,  `*.txt` on level 2

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, that matches my understanding, but is completely different from what Critten said.  Also the conversion of `*.*` to just `*` doesn't matter, you can have a filespec like `file*.t*` which can't be collapsed that way so it really does have multiple wildcards.

Comment: @BenVoigt - yes, you correct.  wildcards allowed only in the last component and in the last component can be any count of *, ? symbols. simply file-system support search by any mask (containing any count of * and ? or at all by empty mask) but only in single folder, which must be exactly specified. the `FindFirstFile[Ex]` normalize name and divide it by last \ symbol to folder path (which must be exactly) and mask.

Comment: Two different answers demonstrate two fundamentally different approaches. or maximal efficient and optimization, but only for windows and more low-level. another try use high level general libs and complex constructs like Regex. this make source code OS independent, but serious loses in memory and speed

Comment: @RbMm Do you have anything to substantiate the claims of "serious loses in memory and speed"?

Comment: @JonathanMee - for example you enumerate all subfolders/files. and on generated full path you apply `Regex` (better use [`RtlIsNameInExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551132(v=vs.85).aspx) here). in another approaches we list not all subfolder, just restrict search. this already can give huge advantage. the `FindFirstFile` serious loses compare `FindFirstFileEx` or `NtQueryDirectoryFile`, i in self solution not allocate any memory, etc. it really very optimized, but of course for windows only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you should do away with using OS specific file access, in favor of the OS independent: [Filesystem Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Let's say that you're given `filesystem::path input` which contains the path with wildcards. To use this to solve your problem you'd need to:

1. Use [`parent_path`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path) to break apart `input` into directories
2. Use [`filename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename) to obtain the `input` filename
3. Obtain a [`directory_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) to the relative or absolute path where the `input` begins
4. Create a recursive function which takes in `begin` and `end` iterators to the obtained parent path, the directory iterator, and the filename
5. Any time a directory or filename uses a `'*'` use a `regex` with the iterator to determine the directory which should be progressed to next
6. Either return the path to the matching file or an empty `path`

Due to [the excellent Ben Voigt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427938/files-in-directory-with-wildcard-on-windows/48428780#comment83855196_48428780) I've updated the algorithm to step over unwildcarded directories.

For example:

```
regex GenerateRegex(string& arg) {
    for (auto i = arg.find('*'); i != string::npos; i = arg.find('*', i + 2)) {
        arg.insert(i, 1, '.');
    }

    return regex(arg);
}

filesystem::path FindFirstFile(filesystem::path directory, filesystem::path::const_iterator& start, const filesystem::path::const_iterator& finish, string& filename) {
    while (start != finish && start->string().find('*') == string::npos) {
        directory /= *start++;
    }
    filesystem::directory_iterator it(directory);
    filesystem::path result;

    if (it != filesystem::directory_iterator()) {
        if (start == finish) {
            for (auto i = filename.find('.'); i != string::npos; i = filename.find('.', i + 2)) {
                filename.insert(i, 1, '\\');
            }
            const auto re = GenerateRegex(filename);

            do {
                if (!filesystem::is_directory(it->status()) && regex_match(it->path().string(), re)) {
                    result = *it;
                    break;
                }
            } while (++it != filesystem::directory_iterator());
        }
        else {
            const auto re = GenerateRegex(start->string());

            do {
                if (it->is_directory() && regex_match(prev(it->path().end())->string(), re)) {
                    result = FindFirstFile(it->path(), next(start), finish, filename);

                    if (!result.empty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while (++it != filesystem::directory_iterator());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which can be called with:

```
const filesystem::path input("C:/Test/Data*Set/Files*/*.txt");

if (input.is_absolute()) {
    const auto relative_parent = input.parent_path().relative_path();

    cout << FindFirstFile(input.root_path(), begin(relative_parent), end(relative_parent), input.filename().string()) << endl;
} else {
    const auto parent = input.parent_path();

    cout << FindFirstFile(filesystem::current_path(), begin(parent), end(parent), input.filename().string()) << endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/f7RUBEE3O9JAUGHk)

Comment: Won't this break if you don't have "List Directory" permission in parent directories which are fully specified?  With the "Bypass File System Traversal Checking" privilege, that should work.  e.g. it should be possible to glob `C:\Users\me\.*\*.tmp`  without being able to list contents of `C:\Users`

Comment: I think you end up wanting to split on the first separator (e.g. `/` or `\ `) following each wildcard (`*` and `?`)

Comment: Note that OP is asking about Windows, and VC++2017 still has filesystem in an experimental namespace.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: A nearly-compatible version of filesystem that works on Windows should be included in Boost, right?

Comment: @Ben Voigt:  <shrug> I haven't used Boost.  You _can_ use filesystem with VC++2017, but you have to be aware that it's in  `std::experimental` rather than `std` and make the appropriate adjustments.  Details:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem

Comment: we not need any regexp. simply need use different file mask in calls `FindFirstFileEx` exist much more efficient solution

Comment: @RbMm I like where your brain is at. Efficiency sounds good, but if you're speaking of efficiency meaning speed, then no, if there are any variations in speed between this and `FindFirstFileEx` those will be far less significant than variations in the file access time. If you're speaking of efficiency as simplicity to read and write code, then no again... but only because the OP is trying to do this cross platform. Were this a Windows only question, it would be simpler to use only `FindFirstFileEx`.

Comment: @BenVoigt OK, I finally got around to updating this. Thank you for the good suggestion. I really enjoy the Filesystem Library, this has been a fun opportunity to practice it.

Comment: which code is more easy to read is indefinitely. can be different results for different peoples :)

Comment: @RbMm There's no question simply calling `FindFirstFileEx` is easier to read, but it's not cross platform. Nor is Microsoft bound to continue to supporting it. The Filesystem library not only gives you cross platform consistent support, but guarantees the presence of your library on any C++17 compiler.

Comment: we simply have fundamentally different approaches. and different opinion what is more easy to read too

Comment: @RbMm I... don't think so. I agree with you that yours is better for Microsoft only code.

Comment: I think it may have sense to change `'.'` dot symbols in string passed to `GenerateRegex` into `"[.]"` in generated regex. Since filename will generally may some and it may lead to search results slightly different from original wildcard.

Comment: man, you're a saint

Answer (score 6):

need understand how `FindFirstFile[Ex]` work. this is shell over [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile). `FindFirstFile[Ex]` need divide input name to folder name (which will be opened in used as *FileHandle*) and search mask used as *FileName*. mask can be only in file name. folder must have exact name without wildcard to opened first.

as result `FindFirstFile[Ex]` always open concrete single folder and search in this folder by mask. for recursive search files - we need recursive call `FindFirstFile[Ex]`. simply usual we use the same constant search mask on all levels. for example when we want find all files begin from `X:\SomeFolder` we first call `FindFirstFile[Ex]` with `X:\SomeFolder\*` on level 0. if we found `SomeSubfolder` - we call `FindFirstFile[Ex]` with `X:\SomeFolder\SomeSubfolder\*` on level 1 and so on.  but we can use **different search masks** on different levels. `Data*Set` on level 0, `Files*` on level 1, `*.txt` on level 2

so we need call `FindFirstFileEx` recursive and on different recursions level use different masks. for example we want found `c:\Program*\*\*.txt`. we need start from `c:\Program*`, then for every founded result append `\*` mask, then append `\*.txt` on next level. or we can for example want next - search files by next mask - `c:\Program Files*\Internet Explorer\*` with any deep level. we can use constant deep search folder mask (optional) with final mask (also optional) used already on all more deep levels.
all this can be really not so hard and efficient implemented:

```
struct ENUM_CONTEXT : WIN32_FIND_DATA 
{
    PCWSTR _szMask;
    PCWSTR *_pszMask;
    ULONG _MaskCount;
    ULONG _MaxLevel;
    ULONG _nFiles;
    ULONG _nFolders;
    WCHAR _FileName[MAXSHORT + 1];

    void StartEnum(PCWSTR pcszRoot, PCWSTR pszMask[], ULONG MaskCount, PCWSTR szMask, ULONG MaxLevel, PSTR prefix)
    {
        SIZE_T len = wcslen(pcszRoot);

        if (len < RTL_NUMBER_OF(_FileName))
        {
            memcpy(_FileName, pcszRoot, len * sizeof(WCHAR));

            _szMask = szMask, _pszMask = pszMask, _MaskCount = MaskCount;
            _MaxLevel = szMask ? MaxLevel : MaskCount;
            _nFolders = 0, _nFolders = 0;

            Enum(_FileName + len, 0, prefix);
        }
    }

    void Enum(PWSTR pszEnd, ULONG nLevel, PSTR prefix);
};

void ENUM_CONTEXT::Enum(PWSTR pszEnd, ULONG nLevel, PSTR prefix)
{
    if (nLevel > _MaxLevel)
    {
        return ;
    }

    PCWSTR lpFileName = _FileName;

    SIZE_T cb = lpFileName + RTL_NUMBER_OF(_FileName) - pszEnd;

    PCWSTR szMask = nLevel < _MaskCount ? _pszMask[nLevel] : _szMask;

    SIZE_T cchMask = wcslen(szMask) + 1;

    if (cb < cchMask + 1)
    {
        return ;
    }

    *pszEnd++ = L'\\', cb--;

    DbgPrint("%s[<%.*S>]\n", prefix, pszEnd - lpFileName, lpFileName);

    memcpy(pszEnd, szMask, cchMask * sizeof(WCHAR));

    ULONG dwError;

    HANDLE hFindFile = FindFirstFileEx(lpFileName, FindExInfoBasic, this, FindExSearchNameMatch, 0, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH);

    if (hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PWSTR FileName = cFileName;

        do 
        {
            SIZE_T FileNameLength = wcslen(FileName);

            switch (FileNameLength)
            {
            case 2:
                if (FileName[1] != '.') break;
            case 1:
                if (FileName[0] == '.') continue;
            }

            if (dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                _nFolders++;

                if (!(dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT))
                {
                    if (cb < FileNameLength)
                    {
                        __debugbreak();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        memcpy(pszEnd, FileName, FileNameLength * sizeof(WCHAR));
                        Enum(pszEnd + FileNameLength, nLevel + 1, prefix - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (nLevel >= _MaskCount || (!_szMask && nLevel == _MaskCount - 1))
            {
                _nFiles++;

                DbgPrint("%s%u%u <%.*S>\n", prefix, nFileSizeLow, nFileSizeHigh, FileNameLength, FileName);
            }

        } while (FindNextFile(hFindFile, this));

        if ((dwError = GetLastError()) == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        {
            dwError = NOERROR;
        }

        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    if (dwError && dwError != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        DbgPrint("%s[<%.*S>] err = %u\n", prefix, pszEnd - lpFileName, lpFileName, dwError);
    }
}

void Test(PCWSTR pcszRoot)
{
    char prefix[MAXUCHAR + 1];
    memset(prefix, '\t', RTL_NUMBER_OF(prefix) - 1);
    prefix[RTL_NUMBER_OF(prefix) - 1] = 0;

    ENUM_CONTEXT ectx;

    static PCWSTR Masks[] = { L"Program*", L"*", L"*.txt" };
    static PCWSTR Masks2[] = { L"Program*", L"*" };
    static PCWSTR Masks3[] = { L"Program Files*", L"Internet Explorer" };

    // search Program*\*\*.txt with fixed deep level
    ectx.StartEnum(pcszRoot, Masks, RTL_NUMBER_OF(Masks), 0, RTL_NUMBER_OF(prefix) - 1, prefix + RTL_NUMBER_OF(prefix) - 1);
    // search *.txt files from Program*\*\ - any deep level
    ectx.StartEnum(pcszRoot, Masks2, RTL_NUMBER_OF(Masks2), L"*.txt", RTL_NUMBER_OF(prefix) - 1, prefix + RTL_NUMBER_OF(prefix) - 1);
    // search all files (*) from Program Files*\Internet Explorer\ 
    ectx.StartEnum(pcszRoot, Masks3, RTL_NUMBER_OF(Masks3), L"*", RTL_NUMBER_OF(prefix) - 1, prefix + RTL_NUMBER_OF(prefix) - 1);

}
```

Comment: Very nice answer, could you please answer mine too ?

Comment: @NorbertBoros are you asking for assistance on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182253/c-queryfullprocessimagenamea-alternative-for-windows-xp)?

Comment: @JonathanMee - At that time yes, at this time I still don't have a definitive solution...