# Does c++17 filesystem has any method to search file name matching with wildcard?

Tags: c++, c++17

My requirement is to find the text files starting with abc under C directory. I am using below piece of code for this.

```
std::string fileNameSearch = "c:\\abc*.txt";
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData{};
if (NULL != FindFirstFile(fileNameSearch.c_str(), &findData))
{
...
...
...
}
```

I would like to remove windows API and use c++ library to do this if available. I can do this with C++17 filesystem and regex. Is it possible to do this only with filesystem methods?

Comment: [Files in directory with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427938/995714)